# flagging every 6 rows in R if there are two (1) within them

Tags: r, group-by, boolean, flags

I have a dataframe (time series(observations in every 10 minutes) in R with 3000 rows . in one column I have 0 and 1 for quality control, I have to check this column to see if in every 6 rows(which make 1 hour) I have two or more than two (1) or not ? and if yes I should flag that group as (Na) . How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are new to SO. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is a good and important read which will make sure you attract people to work on your Question.

Here is a solution for how I understood your question.
A time sequence over one year is created in steps of 10 minutes.

Vector `check` has sampled `0` or `1` over the length of `interval`. For reproducability I have set a seed.

A DF is made out of both.
This DF is grouped for month, day and hour and a value is created which sums the `1` 's per hour. If this number is 2 or greater a new variable `flag` gets an `NA` , if not it gets an empty string.

At the end only the relevant variables are selected.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1)
interval <- seq(ymd_hms('2020-12-01 00:00:00'), 
                by = '10 min',length.out=(60*24*365/10))

check <- sample(c(0,1), length(interval), replace = T)
df <- data.frame(interval, check)

df %>% 
  mutate(hour = hour(interval)) %>% 
  group_by(month(interval),day(interval), hour(interval)) %>% 
  mutate(N = sum(check)) %>% 
  mutate(flag = ifelse(N >= 2, NA, '')) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::select(interval, check,N, flag) 
#> # A tibble: 52,560 x 4
#>    interval            check     N flag 
#>    <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#>  1 2020-12-01 00:00:00     0     2 <NA> 
#>  2 2020-12-01 00:10:00     1     2 <NA> 
#>  3 2020-12-01 00:20:00     0     2 <NA> 
#>  4 2020-12-01 00:30:00     0     2 <NA> 
#>  5 2020-12-01 00:40:00     1     2 <NA> 
#>  6 2020-12-01 00:50:00     0     2 <NA> 
#>  7 2020-12-01 01:00:00     0     2 <NA> 
#>  8 2020-12-01 01:10:00     0     2 <NA> 
#>  9 2020-12-01 01:20:00     1     2 <NA> 
#> 10 2020-12-01 01:30:00     1     2 <NA> 
#> # … with 52,550 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created `flag` variable with `TRUE` and `FALSE` where `TRUE` is when the count of 1 in `check` for a group is greater than equal to 2 and `FALSE` otherwise.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group = ceiling(row_number()/6)) %>%
  mutate(flag = sum(check) >= 2) -> df
```

The same in base R :

```
df$flag <- with(df, ave(check, ceiling(seq_len(nrow(df))/6), FUN = sum) >= 2)
```

If you really want the `flag` to be `NA` instead of `TRUE` you can use :

```
df %>%
  group_by(group = ceiling(row_number()/6)) %>%
  mutate(flag = if(sum(check) >= 2) NA else '') -> df
```